# How the Ruby method scope working?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I use sinatra, and have a question that I can't solve, here is the code:

```
require 'sinatra'

def url(s)
    get  s do yield end
    post s do yield end
end

url '/' do
    erb :index
end
```

then, the program tips that: **undefined method `erb' for main:Object**

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

def map_url(url, options={}, &block)
  get(url, options, &block)
  post(url, options, &block)
end

map_url '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

Comment: Or even: `def map_url(*args, &block); get(*args, &block); post(*args, &block); end`. This should catch everything.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Sinatra Multiroute](http://rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra-contrib/1.3.1/frames).